# Set Heroku environment variable as a function of another dynamic (Heroku-managed) variable

Tags: scala, heroku, foreman, dropwizard

My Scala Dropwizard uses the [SBT Start Script](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-start-script) plugin (commit c1fefeb59f3d6ba053f99b8d49a52779ac3dbce8 at the time of writing) so I can stage a run script which can be easily run with foreman.

However, unlike HOCON, Dropwizard's configuration system allows you to override variables in the YAML file using `-Ddw.xxx` switches via `JAVA_OPTS`.

**I would like to set the port.**

Here-in lies my problem: in the latest version of SBT Start Script, the `JAVA_OPTS` is generated as part of the start script, so you can't pass it in via the Procfile anymore. So, the only way to get the Heroku-managed `$PORT` into my app is to set it via `JAVA_OPTS` as `-Ddw.http.port=$PORT`

**How do I do this?**

I've tried `heroku config:set` arguments on the command line:

- `JAVA_OPTS="-Ddw.http.port=$PORT"` — this evaluates to $PORT in my environment, mostly "".
- `JAVA_OPTS="-Ddw.http.port=\$PORT"` — `heroku config` then shows this as `JAVA_OPTS="-Ddw.http.port=$PORT"`, but the app gets given the literal `$PORT` as the port number, i.e. it doesn't get evaluated on Heroku.
- `JAVA_OPTS="-Ddw.http.port=\\\$PORT"` — `heroku config` then shows this as `JAVA_OPTS="-Ddw.http.port=\$PORT"`, but the app gets given the literal `\$PORT`
- `JAVA_OPTS="-Ddw.http.port=$$PORT"` — `$$` is the pid of the current shell (not subshell), so Heroku sets something like `12345PORT`.

Please let me know how I can set the Heroku-managed port via `JAVA_OPTS`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not address your question (I don't know Scala or `JAVA_OPTS` things) but you can use a [.profile.d script](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/profiled) to dynamically set an environment variable when your app boots. Here's an example where I set a `DATABASE_URL` environment variable using the Heroku API:

```
# .profile.d file
export DATABASE_URL=`curl -s -H "Authorization: Bearer $API_KEY" \
 -X GET https://api.heroku.com/apps/$SOURCE_APP/config-vars \
 -H "Accept: application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3" \
 | grep "DATABASE_URL" | cut -d '"' -f 4 `
```

This script relies on a valid Heroku API key stored in the applications environment variable `API_KEY`, as well as a `SOURCE_APP` environment variable, designating the source app (in your case, itself). In this example I'm checking for `DATABASE_URL`, but you could use what you want.

Comment: Marvellous, thanks. I've been so pre-occupied with AWS recently, I completely missed this new Heroku feature. Pity, though, that ```heroku config``` doesn't show this dynamically-set variable.

Answer (score 1):

@catsby is correct -- you'll want to use the [Heroku Platform API](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference) to do this.

**SIDENOTE**: Heroku's platform API is actually incredibly awesome. You can use it to scale dynos, set variables, provision / deprovision addons, etc.